# Force English MonthName in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My system configurations are set to Hebrew.

I want this function to return an English string:

```
MonthName(month(ActiveSheet.Range("i9").Value)))
```

but it returns Hebrew month name.

I tried to apply what works for me in excel formatting menu but it doesn't seem to work in Vba.
What I tried is to add another argument:

```
MonthName(month(ActiveSheet.Range("i9").Value)),"b1mmmm")
```

with no luck...

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd avoid fighting the locale settings if I were you as whatever you do probably will not end up being portable.

One way, and quite nice insofar that it's a spreadsheet-based solution, is to use

```
=CHOOSE(,"January","February", "March", "April", ..., "December")
```

Where the first argument points to a number between 1 and 12.

In `VBA` you could always set up an array and index that.