# Date formatting VBA with English abbreviation

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following command to format a cell which contains a date.

```
.Range("C6").Value = Format(Me.txtStart.Value, "dd-MMM-yy")
```

So I input for example 01.01.13 and for the cell it converts it to 01-Jan-13 . However, the text, i.e. the MMM part is always in German although I have set the Language of Office to English. For example for March Excel puts in MRZ instead of MAR. Is there an way to make sure it always enters the English abbreviation of the month?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA - Change date language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090315/vba-change-date-language)

Comment: To copy from the answer to the question linked above, you can use the following to force the language of the month: `WorksheetFunction.Text(Date - Day(Date), "[$-409]mmmm")`

Comment: Many thanks!! But where do I have to copy that to exactly to make it work?