# Converting day names to series

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to write a code to convert days into a specific series.
eg.

```
If it is Monday I want - N/Y/N/N/N/N/N
If it is Wednesday I want - N/N/N/Y/N/N/N
if it is Sunday, Friday I want - Y/N/N/N/N/Y/N
```

is there any way I can do this in VBA or excel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the data coming from and where is the output going?

Comment: data is just a column with day names and I want to convert that column into this format.

Comment: so the cell will have week day names comma delineated and you want to change it in place to the output that is `/` delineated?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need VBA to do this. Just use this formula (assuming it's column A). Reminder `alt enter` gives you an enter in a formula to improve readibility.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("Sunday",A:A,0)),"N","Y")&"/"&
 IF(ISERROR(MATCH("Monday",A:A,0)),"N","Y")&"/"&
 IF(ISERROR(MATCH("Tuesday",A:A,0)),"N","Y")&"/"&
 IF(ISERROR(MATCH("Wednesday",A:A,0)),"N","Y")&"/"&
 IF(ISERROR(MATCH("Thursday",A:A,0)),"N","Y")&"/"&
 IF(ISERROR(MATCH("Friday",A:A,0)),"N","Y")&"/"&
 IF(ISERROR(MATCH("Saturday",A:A,0)),"N","Y")
```

If you have to search within cells like "Monday,tuesday" you can use this formula. **THIS IS AN ARRAY FORMULA THAT YOU MUST HIT CTL SHFT ENTER to make work.**

```
=IF(OR(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Sunday",A:A,1)))),"Y","N")&"/"&
IF(OR(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Monday",A:A,1)))),"Y","N")&"/"&
IF(OR(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Tuesday",A:A,1)))),"Y","N")&"/"&
IF(OR(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Wednesday",A:A,1)))),"Y","N")&"/"&
IF(OR(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Thursday",A:A,1)))),"Y","N")&"/"&
IF(OR(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Friday",A:A,1)))),"Y","N")&"/"&
IF(OR(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Saturday",A:A,1)))),"Y","N")&"/"
```

Comment: This will not work on the cells that have multiple in one cell that is comma delineated, like the OP stated in the comments.

Comment: if the user has office 365 Excel: `=TEXTJOIN("/",,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(TEXT(ROW($1:$7),"dddd"),E1)),"Y","N"))` as an array formula.

Comment: Oh jeez, is' that what he's saying?? All right, i'll make an array no vba solution...

Comment: I am not on speaking terms with the Text formula combined with dates. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48155382/dynamically-display-weekday-names-in-native-excel-language

Comment: It has to be used in the array, and I do not like having to type the days out long hand, so I use it so I can copy paste and just change the number.

Comment: @ScottCraner yeah that does make some sense. I'm leaving my answer as it stands for now. Maybe someobody will someday want to do an array search and give me a 

Answer (score 1):

This uses arrays to create the pattern you want.

```
Sub trnsfrm()
Dim rang As Range
Set rang = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:A3") ' Change to your range and worksheet

Dim rng() As Variant
rng = rang.Value

Dim WeekDy As Variant
WeekDy = Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")

Dim outArr(1 To 7) As Variant

Dim j As Long
For j = LBound(rng) To UBound(rng)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(WeekDy) To UBound(WeekDy)
        If InStr(rng(j, 1), WeekDy(i)) > 0 Then
            outArr(i + 1) = "Y"
        Else
            outArr(i + 1) = "N"
        End If
    Next i
    rng(j, 1) = Join(outArr, "/")
Next j

rang.Value = rng


End Sub
```

Turns:

[image]

Into:

[image]

Comment: @ScottCraner I believe both of us made a mistake spending our time on a question that was not well written and the asker just used us to get done whatever is his task, he writes perfectly worked for all of the answer (and they work) while he does not even bother to upvote the answers to appreciates people's time.  I am not going to make the same mistake again and I hope you would not do that too

Comment: @Ibo good luck with that.  Unless you stop answering, which I suggest you continue as many of your answers are better than the accepted, this one included, there will be those that you feel you wasted your time.  I have had answers that are better than the accepted answer ignored and I have had answers of mine that are not as good as others accepted.  It goes both ways.  Remember that many time we do not answer for the immediate problem but those who may have similar questions that come later.

Comment: @ScottCraner I hear you, and I agree with what you say, but I mean answering questions that did not put enough efforts even to write a good question is a mistake by experienced members in here, I will not do that again since I feel I have been used

Comment: @Ibo I understand, most time I do not answer,  I only answered this one because of the puzzle.  I did it to hone my skills.  I wanted to practice with arrays.

Comment: @Ibo I feel your pain. In this case I think the op only did need the excel non-array formula I posted (the wording is questionable). Regardless, it can be a thankless job answering poor questions, putting in time and only to get nothing out of it. Remember that you’re also sharpening your own skills in the process . I consider answering questions kind of like doing a cross word puzzle. I answer questions truly for my own entertainment. If it makes you feel any better, the OP‘s score prevents him giving you an upvote. I gave you a tick though as your answer is cool. ✔️‍♂️⚡️

Comment: @ScottCraner I gave you an upvote, totally forgot that I could do it LOL

Comment: @PGCodeRider thanks! I know everyone has his own reasoning, but this way I learn how to better choose the questions

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking very similar to Scott's approach, but I found a shorter way to do this. Place the code in a module and you can have access to it in the worksheet as a function:

```
Function TagDays(rng As Range)
    strDays = "SUNDAY1MONDAY2TUESDAY3WEDNESDAY4THURSDAY5FRIDAY6SATURDAY7)"
    arr = Array("N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N")
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell <> "" Then
            i = InStr(strDays, UCase(cell))
            If i > 0 Then arr(Mid(strDays, i + Len(cell), 1) - 1) = "Y" '-1 since the LBOUND of arr is 0 not 1
        End If
    Next cell
    TagDays = Join(arr, "/")
End Function
```

Call the function and choose the range you want, it can be more than one column and the result should be updated on the spot even you add or remove days. It is not case sensitive too. Also, it ignores the blank cells.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**EDIT:** the below code can handle the days separated by comma in one cell too, spaces don't matter

```
Function TagDays(rng As Range)
    strDays = "SUNDAY1MONDAY2TUESDAY3WEDNESDAY4THURSDAY5FRIDAY6SATURDAY7)"
    arr = Array("N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N")
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell <> "" Then
            arr2 = Split(cell.Value, ",")
            For j = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
                strday = Trim(UCase(arr2(j)))
                i = InStr(strDays, strday)
                If i > 0 Then arr(Mid(strDays, i + Len(strday), 1) - 1) = "Y" '-1 since the LBOUND of arr is 0 not
            Next j
        End If
    Next cell
    TagDays = Join(arr, "/")
End Function
```

[image]

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Applying the function to cells individually (like Scott's example) will give you this:

[image]

Comment: According to the OP he wanted it in place not in another cell, and that each cell may contain more than one day delineated by a comma.  See the comments.

Comment: @ScottCraner I feel that you suggested to replace the values in place, which in fact is not a good idea because there is no UNDO chance. It seems the asker did not have a clear idea of what he wanted. He answered yes because he did not want to lose the chance of getting help. Honestly, we should have made him edit his question before we offered him free codes

Comment: I added an edit that can handle the comma separated cases too