# Reformatting long date to a different language than the one used in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, date, formatting

I want to change `27/02/2018` into a long date in English `February 27,2018` using a macro.

Recording the steps, I found out that the format for this looks like this : `"[$-en-US]mmmm d, yyyy;@"`

So I did this :

```
cuteDate = Format(DateValue("27/02/2018"), "[$-en-US]mmmm dd, yyyy;@")
```

But wen I run the macro it outputs this : `février 27, 2018` probably because I use Excel in French

How to solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: How is `cuteDate` declared?

Comment: It's a String (I don't need to declare it)

Comment: try: `[$-C0C]mmmm dd, yyyy;@`

Comment: It didn't work, I also tried [$-F800] and [$-409] the outputs is the same

Comment: `cutedate = application.text(DateValue("27/02/2018"), "[$-en-US]mmmm dd, yyyy")`

Comment: @ScottCraner YES it worked!! Thank you so much!! I suggest you post it

Comment: @ScottCraner - Woah, what on earth is the bracket stuff doing? Does that set the region? like [Currency - language - country]?`

Comment: @BruceWayne yes, for example: `application.text(DateValue("27/02/2018"), "[$-407]mmmm dd, yyyy")` returns `Februar 27, 2018`.  `-407` is German, I believe.

Comment: The general rule in the [tag:excel] tag: If Scott can't solve it, no one can.

Comment: @BruceWayne see https://excelribbon.tips.net/T011782_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090315/vba-change-date-language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Scott Craner, this is how you solve it :

```
cutedate = application.text(DateValue("27/02/2018"), "[$-en-US]mmmm dd, yyyy")
```